# Each blitted image in list disappear instead of remaining on screen. I wanted to fill up the whole screen with image as it blits on random locations

Tags: list, pygame, blit

```
import pygame
import random
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((476,800))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 600))
pygame.display.set_caption("DOGGO GAME")
dogimg = pygame.image.load('dog.png')
```

*doglist will contain the image rects so that multiple images/entities will fill the screen

```
doglist = []
dogx = []
dogy = []
```

*blot triggers the creation of element(dog image rect = dogimg)*

```
BLOT = pygame.USEREVENT
pygame.time.set_timer(BLOT, 500)
```

*drawdog blits the images in the doglist*

```
def drawdog(doglist):
    for dog in doglist:
        screen.blit(dogimg, new_dog)


run = True
while run:
    #pygame.time.delay(50)
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == BLOT:
            
            dogimg = pygame.image.load('dog.png')
            dogranx = random.randint(50,200)
            dograny = random.randint(50,450)
            new_dog = dogimg.get_rect(midtop=(dogranx, dograny))
            doglist.append(new_dog)
            print(doglist)


    drawdog(doglist)


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(1)


pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct it by replacing:

```
for dog in doglist
```

with

```
for new_dog in doglist
```

In the former, I was using extend. I changed it to append and used the latter code, and it worked.